# Vietnamese language input method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, methods, http-status-code-500, kiwi-tcms

I'm from Vietnam, We setup a kiwi server, it runs ok. But my problem is I can not write in Vietnam language when we create test case, test plan or write describe. It shows: " 500 Internal error"

Could you pls show me how to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: why writing test case can result 500 internal error? It depends on your backend, your test cases and a lot different stuff. Just asking this generic question isn't going anywhere. At least show what you've done. Describe the scenario, put in some codes...

Answer (score 0):

@Nguyen Van - happy new year first.

There's no need to message us over GitHub, YouTube and StackOverflow simulataneously. It will not help move things faster.

As Eddie has said, let us know some more details:

- what is the actual text that you are trying to enter which results in the error
- how is your Kiwi TCMS instance configured
- what is your operating system, etc ?

Without this information there is nothing we can do to help you.